# Laravel 5 PDO number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo

I'm currently having a trouble on this ...

```
if (Input::has('numenr') and Input::has('table') and Input::has('type') and Input::has('st')) {

    $sql_up = "UPDATE [wds].[dbo].[?] SET [f_nonvint] = ? WHERE [numenr] = '?' AND [f_type] = ?";

    DB::connection('sqlsrv')->update($sql_up, [Input::get('table'), Input::get('st'), Input::get('numenr'), Input::get('type')]);
}
```

The error output is :

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (SQL: UPDATE [wds].[dbo].[f_files_wines] SET [f_nonvint] = 1 WHERE [numenr] = '091DFF89-EB1B-4B81-9BF0-4AB36F65529E' AND [f_type] = 1)
```

The query given looks good and I don't understand where this comes from.

Thank you for your help !  :)

UPDATE :

The previous error is fixed with a little trick. The problem was on the uniqueidentifier. I couldn't add quotes in the sql ... no idea why.
There is the fix :

```
if (Input::has('numenr') and Input::has('table') and Input::has('type') and Input::has('st')) {

    $sql_up = "UPDATE [wds].[dbo].[?] SET [f_nonvint] = ? WHERE [numenr] = ? AND [f_type] = ?";

    DB::connection('sqlsrv')->update($sql_up, [Input::get('table'), Input::get('st'), "'".Input::get('numenr')."'", Input::get('type')]);
}
```

But now I'm getting an even stranger problem.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 208 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: UPDATE [wds].[dbo].[t_files_wines] SET [f_nonvint] = 1 WHERE [numenr] = '7AEDE4A0-0109-4729-8AFE-D4A55A0A5893' AND [f_type] = 2)
```

But the fact is when I copy the query to the SqlServer, I have nothing wrong !  :(

Comment: Error 208 means 'invalid object' - did you check that you are connected to the correct server (if the statment works in SSMS it could no misspelling)? Some times ago I had a similar problem until I realized that I was connected to an older copy of the dev database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using DB::statement([MY SQL UPDATE]) ...
Don't know why it wasn't working ...
I could have used Eloquent but I have a constraint to keep the more SQL.

Thank you guys anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can't parameterize the table name itself (you have to do add it direct into the sql statment).

One of the reasons for this behavior is, that the SQL server build its query plans depending on the transmitted SQL statment. But how should it build a query plan, if it does not know which table he should use. It would be the same as I want you to tell me, how long you need to bring me some parts from a factory but do not tell you from which factory (it could be the small one over the street or another half around the world).

Comment: PDO is doing the job, not SQL Server. He prepares the query before sending the correct SQL to the server.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that (I'm a SQL guy). The drawback of this behavior is, that it will lead to plan cache pollution (if every query paramaeter is replaced with its value than you will get two different plans for two different query parameters).